# How to compute the stalks of $\mathbb{G}_{m}/\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}$ over infinite points?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently studying Mazur's paper.

In the paper, we assume that a number field $K$ is totally imaginary.
I think that this is because he did not want to deal with the infinite points.

My question is

> How to compute the stalks of $\mathbb{G}_{m}/\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}$ over infinite points for totally non-imaginary field?

Note that $\mathbb{G}_{m}/\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}$ is the multiplicative group scheme of mod $n$.

For a totally imaginary case, we know that the sheaf is 0 outside of the points whose residue characteristic divides $n$ by using the pull-back to $spec(\mathbb{F}_{\#k(x)})$.

I guess that it could depend on the characteristic of the number field, but not explicitly.

Furthermore, after the computation, can we show that the $q$th-cohomology group of the sheaf for totally non-imaginary group vanishes for $q\ge1$ with the same way in the paper?

Thank you for your time and effort.

**Reference**

*Mazur, Barry*, [**Notes on etale cohomology of number fields**](http://dx.doi.org/10.24033/asens.1257), Ann. Sci. Éc. Norm. Supér. (4) 6, 521-552 (1973). [ZBL0282.14004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0282.14004).

Comment: i have cross-posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590529/how-to-compute-the-stalks-of-mathbbg-m-mathbbg-mn-over-infinite-p) to MSE.

Comment: In the "completed" etale site of ${\rm{Spec}}(O_K)$ for a number field $K$ one has extra "points" just for real places. For the sheaf $F$ on this site that plays the role of $\mathbf{G}_m$, the "stalk" of $F$ at a real place $v$ is the multiplicative group of positive (nonzero) elements of the algebraic closure of $K$ in $K_v \simeq \mathbf{R}$. More specifically, from the definition of $F$ one sees $F/[n](F)$ vanishes over the enhanced etale site of ${\rm{Spec}}(O_K[1/n])$. See sections 2.2-2.4 and 3.3 (esp. Definition 3.3.1) in http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/Notes/L4.pdf